# Kubernetes use private DNS

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

Is it possible to use a private DNS in Kubernetes? For example, an application needs to connect to an external DB by its hostname. The DNS entry, which resolves the IP, is deposited in a private DNS.

My AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) is running on version 1.17 which already uses the new coreDNS.

My first try was to use that private DNS like on VM by configuring the /etc/resolve.conf file of the pods:

```
dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 10.76.xxx.xxx
      - 10.76.xxx.xxx
    searches:
      - az-q.example.com
    options:
      - name: ndots
        value: "2"
```

Then I tried to use configmap to adjust the coreDNS:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  upstreamNameservers: |
    ["10.76.xxx.xxx", "10.76.xxx.xxx"]
```

But my pod is every time running in an error on deployment:

```
$ sudo kubectl logs app-homepage-backend-xxxxx -n ingress-nginx
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND az-q.example.com az-q.example.com:636
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you need, I'd go with `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst` definition in the pod manifests and then a definition of a stub zone (private DNS zone) in your cluster DNS subsystem.

For identifying the Cluster DNS stack, typically check the pods running in the `kube-system` namespace. Most likely you'll find one of these two: CoreDNS or Kube-DNS.

In case your cluster DNS runs on **CoreDNS**, then look for [this](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/kubernetes/README.md#stubdomains-and-upstreamnameservers) kind of a modification in your `coredns` configmap.
If you run on the older **Kube-DNS** system, then look for [this](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/04/configuring-private-dns-zones-upstream-nameservers-kubernetes/) modification in `kube-dns` configmap.

It's important to say that if you would like to apply this modification to pods running in the host network mode (many pods from `kube-system` namespace), you need to modify their manifests with `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` stanza.

Answer (score 1):

Everyting depends on [dnsPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) you set in deployment configuration file of your application.

When  Pod’s dnsPolicy is set to `“default”,` it inherits the name resolution configuration from the node that the Pod runs on. The Pod’s DNS resolution should behave the same as the node.

**1.** Many Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu), use a local DNS resolver by
    default (systemd-resolved). Systemd-resolved moves and replaces
    `/etc/resolv.conf` with a stub file that can cause a fatal forwarding
    loop when resolving names in upstream servers. This can be fixed
    manually by using kubelet’s `--resolv-conf` flag to point to the
    correct resolv.conf (With systemd-resolved, this is
    `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`). kubeadm (>= **1.11**) automatically
    detects systemd-resolved, and adjusts the kubelet flags accordingly.

Kubernetes installs do not configure the nodes’ resolv.conf files to
    use the cluster DNS by default, because that process is inherently
    distribution-specific. This should probably be implemented
    eventually.

**2.**  Linux’s libc is impossibly stuck (see this bug from 2005) with
    limits of just 3 DNS nameserver records and 6 DNS search records.
    Kubernetes needs to consume 1 nameserver record and 3 search
    records. This means that if a local installation already uses 3
    nameservers or uses more than 3 searches, some of those settings
    will be lost. As a partial workaround, the node can run dnsmasq
    which will provide more nameserver entries, but not more search
    entries. You can also use kubelet’s `--resolv-conf` flag.

**3**. Make sure that you are not using  Alpine version **3.3** or earlier as
    your base image, DNS may not work properly then.

Please take a look here: [dns-kubernetes-known-issues](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues).

Answer (score 0):

What is the `dnsPolicy` set to in the deployment configuration for the application? According to [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#effects-on-pods):

> Custom upstream nameservers and stub domains do not affect Pods with a
>   `dnsPolicy` set to “`Default`” or “`None`”.
>
> If a Pod’s `dnsPolicy` is set to “`ClusterFirst`”, its name resolution is
>   handled differently, depending on whether stub-domain and upstream DNS
>   servers are configured.

See in that doc the example and what happens with custom configurations.